# How to open multiple git bash terminals in windows and execute corresponding commands in each automatically in Windows 10?

Tags: bash, git-bash

I want to just open my git bash once and execute a simple command like bash abc.sh

This should open 2 terminals each having a different set of commands.

Terminal 1:

```
cd '/some/path'
redis-server.exe
```

Terminal 2:

```
cd /some/path
some command
```

Also the terminal should not close on its own.

I am new to this. How should I achieve this ?

Comment: What OS/distribution/desktop manager are you using? The answer will depend on that

Comment: windows 10. git bash.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use conemu: https://conemu.github.io

> ConEmu-Maximus5 aims to be handy, comprehensive, fast and reliable terminal window where you may host any console application developed either for WinAPI (cmd, powershell, far) or Unix PTY (cygwin, msys, wsl bash).

Comment: thnx. but I want to have achieve this using Git Bash only.

Comment: It can help u to use more than one git-bash in one window